# how to get all installed applications of windows using c#

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I've tried `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` to get all application installed in my computer and getting a list of application also but I need to get all applications listed in add or remove program feature of windows.

Please help me to get this solution.

Comment: please format your question.

Comment: I don't think the registry would miss anything you could see in "add or remove program". Any further comments?

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Simonzhao. That registry location is the only place  Add or Remove Programs checks for installed software.

Comment: @ThePcLuddite Not true. "Add or Remove Programs" consults other locations, too. If you want to show the same thing as "Add or Remove Programs", [you can ask for its contents via the shell programming model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/12/30/10485905.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondChen What other locations does it use? The linked article just talks about getting the list from the control panel applet itself.

Comment: The list of places that "Add and Remove Programs" gets its programs from keeps changing. If you want to get the same list that "Add and Remove Programs" uses, then just ask Add and Remove Programs for its list.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could use WMI, like this:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
foreach(ManagementObject mgmtObjectin searcher .Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(mgmtObjectin ["Name"]);
}
```

Another posibility is to use SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall for 32 bit applications and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall for 64 bits applications and merge the lists, I think your code should looks like:

```
string registry_key_32 = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
string registry_key_64 = @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

using(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key_32))
{
    foreach(string name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using(RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));
        }
    }
}
// And...
using(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key_64))
{
    foreach(string name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using(RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` is actually used for 32-bit applications on 64-bit machines. 64-bit applications are put directly it `HKLM\SOFTWARE`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64#Registry_and_file_system